# NoMethodError - undefined method `email' for #<ActionDispatch::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Devise 3.5.2, Rails 4.2.3

While logging in, I'm trying to pass a hidden role_id along with the email/password combination. I am allowing the same email to register again, on a different subdomain, which causes a different role_id to be passed. The email+role_id is the unique index for the user.

I can create a user, but cannot log in. When I submit the log in form, I am faced with the following error:

`undefined method 'email' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007fa21628bda0>`

## EDIT:

If anyone can explain the process of changing the email uniqueness validation to email+role_id (not either/or, but and), that's all I need to accomplish. Following that process properly may avoid this error.

### Debugging info:

The POST parameters are as follows:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "member"=>{"role_id"=>"1",
 "email"=>"some.user@email.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "remember_me"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Log in"}
```

Here is my Member model:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable

  belongs_to :role

  def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
    where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :role_id => warden_conditions[:role_id]).first
  end
end
```

In *config/initializers/devise.rb*, the following is set:

`config.authentication_keys = [:email, :role_id]`

`config.request_keys = [:email, :role_id]`

My views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb includes:

`<%= f.hidden_field :role_id, :value => Role.find_by_name(current_subdomain).id %>`

I adjusted *vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb* by changing this line:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
```

to:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :role_id, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed? #using subdomains for validation
```

The relevant database migrations for the member are found here:

#### ...devise_create_members.rb

```
class DeviseCreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:members) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :members, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :members, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :members, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    add_index :members, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
```

#### ...add_columns_to_member.rb

```
class AddColumnsToMember < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :members, :contact, index: true
    add_reference :members, :role, index: true
    add_reference :members, :ownership, index: true
    add_column :members, :account_status, :string
  end
end
```

#### ...reindex_members_email_and_role.rb

```
class ReindexMembersEmailAndRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :members, [:email, :role_id], :unique => true
  end
end
```

The last item on the trace is:

*vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb:152:in `block in request_values'*

```
    keys = request_keys.respond_to?(:keys) ? request_keys.keys : request_keys
    values = keys.map { |k| self.request.send(k) } <--ERROR THIS LINE
    Hash[keys.zip(values)]
  end
```

#### What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please post the controller and the database migration for Member?

Comment: @Tommyixi Devise has no controller for the user model ("member" model in my case). I added to my question some other changes I made to the project I thought might be relevant, clarified my intent, and added migration and trace info.

Comment: @Tommyixi I figured it out :) Thanks for taking a look at this for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, I changed my `config/initializers/devise.rb` to reflect the following:

`config.request_keys = { role_id: false }`

This fixed the issue, but still prevented the same email from signing up with a different role ID. To fix this, I removed `:validatable` from my User model and added:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of   :email,    :case_sensitive => false, :scope => :role_id, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  validates_format_of       :email,    :with  => Devise.email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  validates_presence_of     :password, :on=>:create
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :on=>:create
  validates_length_of       :password, :within => Devise.password_length, :allow_blank => true
```

This allows the same email address to sign up with a different role_id.

I also changed the following in authenticatable.rb:

```
      def request_values
        keys = request_keys.respond_to?(:keys) ? request_keys.keys : request_keys
        values = keys.map { |k| self.request[self.scope][k] }
#        values = keys.map { |k| self.request.send(k) }
        Hash[keys.zip(values)]
      end
```

**UPDATE**

I got tired of always having to re-hack the devise library, especially after I updated gems or transferred the app. I found this page that offered a better work-around (still follow the step regarding validations the User model listed above):

(From https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3965)

Comment out the following line we edited above:

`# config.request_keys = { role_id: false }`

Edit the `config.authentication_keys` line as follows:

`config.authentication_keys = { email: true, role_id: false }`

The issue is that `request_keys` honors only predefined keys such as `:subdomain`.

That should work now for creating a combination of custom keys to authenticate with.

Comment: You don't know how long I struggled with this issue.  So glad I found this post.  So the wiki article about this topic is not correct because it ignores authentication_keys and recommends changing request_keys.  It seems.

Comment: @Phil, see the amended answer for the proper fix.

Comment: Good to know that request_keys only honors predefined keys such as :subdomain. I spent a while wondering why subdomain would work but not store_id.